# Custom Unity Preview Window With Canvas Object

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine, inspector

I want to create a custom preview window that does something like this but with a Canvas not a Mesh:

[image]

After much digging I found a `PreviewRenderUtility` tool but [there is no documentation on it](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=PreviewRenderUtility). I found a tutorial which shows me how to use it for a MeshRenderer but I need to use it for a Canvas object. There is a call that does the mesh renderer as such:

```
_previewRenderUtility.DrawMesh(_targetMeshFilter.sharedMesh, Matrix4x4.identity, _targetMeshRenderer.sharedMaterial, 0);
```

Do you know if there is an equivalent for rendering Canvas objects in the preview window?

Answer (score -1):

I made Unity asset for previewing:
 https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/82899
Also I made free extension to it, that works with Canvas, maybe it will be useful for you:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/86480
If you have any questions, write me a letter: startassets@gmail.com